# Can I use Bluetooth headphones with a Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I know I can plug in a 3.5 mm headphone plug into the Switch, but is there a way to sync Bluetooth headphones instead?

Answer (score 8):

**Update:**

Since posting, an update released in September of 2021 introduced  "regular Bluetooth" connectivity (without the need of an adapter or dongle, as discussed in the [other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/326470/163757)).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Switch#Connectivity) states:

> This was later fully resolved in a system update in September 2021 when it enabled support for Bluetooth Wireless headphone devices without the need for a USB adapter.

---

**Original Post:**

According to [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Switch) for the Switch:

> The unit does not directly support Bluetooth wireless headphones, though they can be connected with third-party wireless adapters via the headphone jack.

Without the use of a third party connectivity device that you plug into the headphone jack, the Switch does not natively support Bluetooth headphones. [One article](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/05/you_can_use_bluetooth_headphones_on_your_switch_but_theres_a_catch) I found shows how you can use one of these devices. It should be fairly straightforward.  All you should have to do is pair the Bluetooth device with your headphones.

Unfortunately, this means you will have to make an additional purchase. Also be warned that each Bluetooth device will be different in how you pair the device with your headphones, and the article says that the one they used had a decent amount of audio delay as well.